# Paper.js boolean unite() gives error

Tags: javascript, paperjs

Take a look at [this page](http://zrispo.co/booleantests.html).

It gives this error when after trying to `unite()` the two SVGs:

```
paper-full.js:9309 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_intersection' of null
```

The two SVGs are proper SVGs - you can see them being rendered correctly at the bottom of the page. After being imported into paper.js, they become a Path and a CompoundPath that render correctly as well. But when I call `path1.unite(path2);` I get the weird error.

Is this something I'm doing wrong? I'm not too familiar with SVGs.

Comment: This looks like a bug in paper.js boolean code. Can you please report it at https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: Check out the issue I posted on paper.js's github repo: https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/1100

Basically you're only supposed to use `unite()` when the two paths being united are closed paths.